# Create a skewed (non-physical) camera with a custom matrix

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I'm creating a stylized world where the vertical dimension is distorted relative to the forward dimension.

Right now in script, I'm doing :

```
custom_matrix = mathutils.Matrix((
    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    (0.0, .707106829, -.707106829, 0.0),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
))
    # Check if the camera already exists
camera_object = bpy.data.objects.get(camera_name)
camera_object.matrix_world = custom_matrix

// Works fine
print(camera_object.matrix_world)

// Update the view layer
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

// After any kind of update, the camera normalizes to a matrix I didn't set
print(camera_object.matrix_world)
```

Is setting a custom projection matrix possible in Blender?

Comment: Sounds like there are rot/scale keyframes on the camera